# Platforms besides Magento that use EAV (Entity Attribute Value) table structures

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

In working with Magento's EAV system, I have developed a PHP-based tool which will assemble the tables' data back into a tabular format as well as identify "holes" in the attributes between or across products.  It works with both the product and category system, and allows determining if an attribute has NOT been inserted into a particular product, or if data is consistent across stores, or stores which are inconsistent - things that are not easy through normal SQL queries and which might be tough to program with Magento native coding.

I plan to post a link to this via github and here when complete.

My question is, are there other platforms or system which make use of EAV?  I would like to make my application as system-agnostic as possible.  Thanks.